# Como saco el valor de un elemento hijo de un div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, dom

Hola quisiera saber como extraer el valor de un `<input id="tipo"/>` hijo de un `<div class="box-header">` estos elementos del `DOM` se repiten pero no sus valores, los valores los ocupo para setear un local storage , hay alguien que me pueda ayudar con una sugerencia , me interesa aprender  a referirme a los elementos hijos con jquery, la estructura es la siguiente

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.box-header').click(function () {
    alert("clickeed")
    var tipo = $('b').parent('.box-header').val();
    localStorage.setItem("tipoDocto", tipo);
    //var tipo = $('#tipo').val();
    // 
    // localStorage.setItem("tipo", tipo);
  });
});
</script>

<div id="este"  class="box-header" data-widget="collapse" >
  <img id="lupa" src="css/galeria/zoom.png" 
    style="float:left; width:14px;height:18px; margin-left:2%;margin-top: 3%;" />

  <h2 class="box-title" display="block" 
    style="float:left; margin-left:2%;"> {{item.documentos}} </h2>

  <img id="change" src="css/galeria/down.png" 
    style="float:right; width:7%;margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 4%;" />

  <input type="text" id="tipo" readonly>{{item.clave}}</>
  <div class="box-tools pull-right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si los elementos se repiten, no deberías tener ID's , en su lugar clases, luego para encontrar el elemento hijo solo bastaría utilizar [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) con el selector de la clase que le pertenece al `input`  *(tipo)*.

Ojo que debería modificar los id para los elementos `#lupa`  , `#change`  , `#este`  y `#tipo` , deberías cambiarlo a clases, ya que como mencionas son elementos que se repiten.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.box-header').click(function () {
    //this hace referencia al div , luego buscamos el elemento 
    // con la clase tipo y obtenemos su valor
    let tipo = $(this).find('.tipo').val();
    console.log(tipo);
    //asignas al storage
    //localStorage.setItem("tipoDocto", tipo);
  });
});
```

```css
.box-header{
  background: #ccc;
  margin:2em;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-header" data-widget="collapse" >

    <img class="lupa" src="css/galeria/zoom.png" style="float:left; width:14px;height:18px; margin-left:2%;margin-top: 3%;" />

    <h2 class="box-title" display="block" style="float:left; margin-left:2%;"> {{item.documentos}} </h2>
    <img class="change" src="css/galeria/down.png" style="float:right; width:7%;margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 4%;" />
    <input type="text" class="tipo" readonly value="tipo1">
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-header" data-widget="collapse" >

    <img class="lupa" src="css/galeria/zoom.png" style="float:left; width:14px;height:18px; margin-left:2%;margin-top: 3%;" />

    <h2 class="box-title" display="block" style="float:left; margin-left:2%;"> {{item.documentos}} </h2>
    <img class="change" src="css/galeria/down.png" style="float:right; width:7%;margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 4%;" />
    <input type="text" class="tipo" readonly value="tipo2">
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que quieras hacer algo  como esto:

```
var id = $('input').attr('id');
```

un ejemplo:

```js
var id = $('input').attr('id');
alert(id);
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>ejemplo</title>
</head>  
<body>

<div><!-- el padre -->
  
  <!-- tu quieres tomar el id de este hijo del padre div de arriba-->
<input type='text' id='hello' />
  </div>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```